# FreshBooks Online Account

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, online-accounts, oauth

I'm developing an application that connects to [FreshBook](http://freshbooks.com)'s API.  I can either integrate the account authentication process within my application, or I can develop an Online Account that could be used by other application developers.

I've looked at some of the code in the existing Online Accounts (with reference from [How do I use OAuth from an Ubuntu Touch app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336069/how-do-i-use-oauth-from-an-ubuntu-touch-app)).  However, FreshBooks is a bit more complicated.  The way they work, each account has a dedicated sub-domain, each with its own separate OAuth URL.  I can't just put a fixed endpoint in the code.

So my question is, how would I go about adding a field before the OAuth process that collects the sub-domain from the user, before opening the OAuth form page?  I'm starting from zero knowledge of how Online Accounts are implemented, so I don't know where to start.

**Edit**: as a workaround, I put the OAuth process directly into my application, see this question: [Get Qt WebKit HTML Content in QML](https://askubuntu.com/q/422277/18764)