# Get Qt WebKit HTML Content in QML

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

My application is built with QML (Ubuntu SDK), and I need to get the HTML content from a page loaded with a Qt `WebView` after the page is loaded.  Based on some initial research, it would appear that this used to be directly supported, but not anymore.  I'm using Qt 5/QtWebKit 3.  How can I get the source from the page with JavaScript?

**Edit**: I found out about the `experimental` object, but I've still not found what I need.  More here: http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html

**Edit**: just a broader perspective on what I'm trying to do.  My application attaches to a user's Freshbooks account through OAuth.  After they've entered their credentials, I need to be able to access the OAuth verifier code from the content of the page.  Via the OAuth protocol, I don't know of any other way to get this code.  I can't even have the user copy-paste it over, because you can't select text in the WebView :(

Comment: Do you need to display the page in a WebView, or do you just want the source of the page and are trying to use a WebView to get it?

Comment: @dobey I need to display it.  The user is interacting with the page, and then I need to extract content from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you should be able to do this by running some Javascript inside the WebView with `WebView.experimental.evaluateJavaScript()`.  This Javascript could get the page source (or better yet, just the content you want, since it'll be better at parsing HTML than the Javascript-in-QML) and report it back via the document title.  For example,

```
webview.experimental.evaluateJavaScript(
    "document.title = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML")
```

I'll admit that I don't know much about OAuth, but I can't help but feel you're doing something wrong if you need to do this.  Have you checked out [Online Accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336069/how-do-i-use-oauth-from-an-ubuntu-touch-app?sgp=2) or this [OAuth plugin](https://code.launchpad.net/~josephjamesmills/+junk/OAuth_Playground)?

Comment: That's the solution I finally came to, I found code [here](https://github.com/rschroll/beru/commit/ac3336f620a8da8b384d4e999e9ac43cc51b369d).  I looked into Online Accounts (in fact I [asked about it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/420014/freshbooks-online-account)), but have not gotten a response.  It's a little more complicated than just an OAuth request, through I would love to do it that way.